# Map array object inside map - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am planning to map each item in the object (contact numbers) for every Person
Putting it inside  and seperate them in **comma** '**,**'
When I use **data.contact_number**, output is combined all fields in array.

```
const ContactList = (props) => (
          <div>
              <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Contact Numbers</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Email</th>
                      <th>Note</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {props.data.map(data =>
                    <tr key={data.id}>
                      <td>{data.name}</td>
                          {props.data[data.id].contact_number.map(cn =>   
                           <td>{cn}</td>
                          )}
                      <td>{data.address}</td>
                      <td>{data.email}</td>
                      <td>{data.note}</td>
                    </tr>
                    )}
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>  
        )
```

**This is my data:**

```
 {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "sd",
        "email": "ajot@qwe.com",
        "address": "testAddress",
        "note": "testNote",
        "contact_number": [
            "11",
            "12",
            "31",
            "41",
            "51",
            "61"
        ]
    }
```

Error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact_number'
>   of undefined

Comment: props.data[data.id] should obviously be data.contact_number. Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const ContactList = (props) => (
      <div>
          <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Contact Numbers</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Note</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {props.data.map(data =>
                <tr key={data.id}>
                  <td>{data.name}</td>
                  <td>{data.contact_number.map(cn => cn).join(', ')}</td>
                  <td>{data.address}</td>
                  <td>{data.email}</td>
                  <td>{data.note}</td>
                </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>  
    )
```

This line which I have changed should give you your desired effect:
`{data.contact_number.map(cn => cn).join(', ')}` by writing all the contact_number values to a string separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
{props.data[data.id].contact_number.map(cn =>   
  <td>{cn}</td>
)}
```

by this :

```
{data.contact_number.map(cn =>   
  <td>{cn}</td>
)}
```

`props.data[data.id]` is undefined because `props.data[data.id]` is not equal to `data`

Comment: Thank you, it is working with this, but it is returning each **</td>**

Answer (score 0):

The data-path is wrong:

```
props.data[data.id].contact_number
```

or the data have to be structured like

```
[7 : {
    "name": "sd",
    "email": "ajot@qwe.com",
    "address": "testAddress",
    "note": "testNote",
    "contact_number": [
        "11",
        "12"
    ]
  },
 8 : { ... },
 0 : { ... }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your json.

[`JSON.parse(yourJson)`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) turns the data into a JavaScript object.

`JSON.parse(props.data).map(data => ...`

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try this for my future features.

Answer (score 0):

If you see properly data is not an array so you can't use map on that. You can simply choose this.

```
const ContactList = (props) => (
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Contact Numbers</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Note</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr key={this.props.data.id}>
                <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
                {this.props.data.contact_number.map((contact_number)=>{
                    <td>{contact_number}</td>
                })}                
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>  
)
```